# Robot framework - remove duplicates from bi-dimensional array

Tags: robotframework

I need to store correlated variables in a bi-dimensional array, like

```
[0][0]=[link1][AAA]
[1][1]=[link1][BBB]
[2][2]=[link3][CCC]
[3][3]=[link4][DDD]
```

I need to remove duplicates related to first dimension [*][n], so I need to produce an output like:

```
[0][0]=[link1][AAA]
[2][2]=[link3][CCC]
[3][3]=[link4][DDD]
```

I've looked to roboframework collection, but I'm confused on how to implement it.
I can create the array

```
*** Variables ***
@{array_1}         link1   link1    link3    link4
@{array_2}        AAA    BBB    CCC    DDD
@{array_bi}         ${array_1}    ${array_2}
```

But I cannot use the "Remove Duplicates" methods, as it apply on a single list and it won't keep right index of untouched list=>  ${array_bi[x][x]}

Any suggestion is really appreciated!
Many Thanks!

Comment: So you have the array of data and want to remove duplicates or you build the array from simple data?

Comment: @ClaudioBatista I have the array of data and I need to remove duplicates related to 1 dimension as per my example

Comment: can you just post the code you have and even the result of logging the data?

Comment: @ClaudioBatista I was not even able to test as Remove Duplicates is not working from bi-dimensional array https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Remove%20Duplicates